# RemoveClass not working on a class name just added using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For some reason when I add a class to an element using Jquery I cannot perform a function using the class name just added:

```
 $('.openslidecontent .arrow.off').click(function() {  
        $('.openslidecontent,.rightwrapper .arrow').removeClass('off')
        $('.openslidecontent,.rightwrapper .arrow').addClass('on');
      return false;
     });

    $('.openslidecontent .arrow.on').click(function() {   // THIS FUNCTION DOES NOT EXECUTE
        $('.openslidecontent,.rightwrapper .arrow').removeClass('on');
        $('.openslidecontent,.rightwrapper .arrow').addClass('off');
      return false;
     });
```

Comment: Not sure about your issue, but why not just use `toggleClass()` instead and you'd be able to merge those two callbacks into one. See: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: You're binding to an element with the class `on`, but that class is added dynamically. To keep things the way you have them, you'd have to do `$('.openslidecontent .arrow').on('click', '.on', function() ...`. However, I would follow Scott's advice and use `toggleClass()`.

Comment: You would need to use a delegated event handler as you're changing classes at run time. As @ScottMarcus says though, using `toggleClass()` is a much better solution entirely.

Comment: I do not want to use toggleClass, because I need to a different classname to close with to perform a different function.

Comment: That makes no sense. Can you explain what you actually want to do, as the answer below fits logic of the code example you provided perfectly.

Comment: Rory, read my update. Like this I have to perform the same function with the toggle of on and off, but I need to perform a different function on the off.

Comment: The answer does work as described, I must have another problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event listener is only attached to existing elements. You can switch to event delegation to have the listener react on newly created elements too

```
$(document).on('click', '.openslidecontent .arrow', function() {
    $('.openslidecontent,.rightwrapper .arrow').toggleClass('on off');
})
```

Also, as Rory commented, you can just change your code to use `toggleClass()` and hook the event to both at the same time

Comment: `You should do the same for both handlers` not if you hook the event to both at the same time and just do `toggleClass('on off')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks, changed that

Comment: I do not want to use toggleClass, because I need to a perform a different function when closing.

Comment: Ok, you can still use it with your code, just add `.on` / `.off` to the selector in `.on()` @Omar

Comment: Or do a check for `hasClass('on')` before you do the toggle

Comment: Also this is add both on and off class to the .openslidecontent element